# Counting previous incidents

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

First time asker here:

I have data with dates and people that represent events. I want to find a way to count the number of times a person was previously involved. So I want data that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq(ymd('2018-01-01'),ymd('2018-01-10'), by = '1 day'),
             id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2, 1, 4),
             # how many previous times has this id been seen?
             count_before = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1))

df

   date          person_id count_before
 1 2018-01-01    1.           0.
 2 2018-01-02    2.           0.
 3 2018-01-03    3.           0.
 4 2018-01-04    4.           0.
 5 2018-01-05    3.           1.
 6 2018-01-06    5.           0.
 7 2018-01-07    2.           1.
 8 2018-01-08    2.           2.
 9 2018-01-09    1.           1.
10 2018-01-10    4.           1.
```

I don't have experience working row-wise in R (sapply is maybe the answer?) but thinking through this problem using dplyr summarize and group_by have failed so far.

**Edit**: fixed the inconsistency in the expected output.

Comment: This seems inconsistent. `2.` appears in row 2 (count 0), row 7 (count 2), and row 8 (count 1). It's probably a typo, but answering questions is difficult when the "expected output" is not consistent with the description.

Comment: Sorry about that! Happy people could figure it out despite the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, providing what I think you intended as your expected count.

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(ymd('2018-01-01'),ymd('2018-01-10'), by = '1 day'),
             id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2, 1, 4))
df %>%
   arrange(date) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(count_before = row_number() - 1L) %>%
   ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 × 3
#          date    id count_before
#        <date> <dbl>        <int>
# 1  2018-01-01     1            0
# 2  2018-01-02     2            0
# 3  2018-01-03     3            0
# 4  2018-01-04     4            0
# 5  2018-01-05     3            1
# 6  2018-01-06     5            0
# 7  2018-01-07     2            1
# 8  2018-01-08     2            2
# 9  2018-01-09     1            1
# 10 2018-01-10     4            1
```

Base R:

```
do.call(rbind, by(df, df$id, function(a) { a$count <- seq.int(nrow(a))-1L; a;}))
#            date id count
# 1.1  2018-01-01  1     0
# 1.9  2018-01-09  1     1
# 2.2  2018-01-02  2     0
# 2.7  2018-01-07  2     1
# 2.8  2018-01-08  2     2
# 3.3  2018-01-03  3     0
# 3.5  2018-01-05  3     1
# 4.4  2018-01-04  4     0
# 4.10 2018-01-10  4     1
# 5    2018-01-06  5     0
```

Comment: Thank you! I prefer dplyr so this is great. Have to work through it to make sure I get it (I've never seen the row_count function or 1L) but I really appreciate it.

Comment: `1L` (or any number with a trailing `L`) is a true "integer" in R. I do this partly for pedagogic completeness, partly for code-consistency (to reinforce that `row_number()` returns in `integer` and not a `numeric`), and partly (barely) for [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). It'll work just fine without the `L`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `base R` solution. Also think you have a typo in your expected output, as mentioned by @r2evans.

```
transform(df, count_new = ave(person_id, person_id, FUN = function(x) cumsum(x == x) - 1))
#         date person_id count_before count_new
#1  2018-01-01         1            0         0
#2  2018-01-02         2            0         0
#3  2018-01-03         3            0         0
#4  2018-01-04         4            0         0
#5  2018-01-05         3            1         1
#6  2018-01-06         5            0         0
#7  2018-01-07         2            2         1
#8  2018-01-08         2            1         2
#9  2018-01-09         1            1         1
#10 2018-01-10         4            1         1
```

Comment: `ave` is what I was thinking about (without remembering the actual function) when I thought to do a base solution, but I couldn't think of it quickly enough. +1

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `data.table`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(date = seq(ymd('2018-01-01'),ymd('2018-01-10'), by = '1 day'),
                 id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2, 1, 4))

setDT(df)

df[, count_before := seq_len(.N) - 1, by = id]
df
#           date id count_before
#  1: 2018-01-01  1            0
#  2: 2018-01-02  2            0
#  3: 2018-01-03  3            0
#  4: 2018-01-04  4            0
#  5: 2018-01-05  3            1
#  6: 2018-01-06  5            0
#  7: 2018-01-07  2            1
#  8: 2018-01-08  2            2
#  9: 2018-01-09  1            1
# 10: 2018-01-10  4            1
```

We can also do the following.

```
df[, count_before := rowid(id) - 1]
df
#           date id count_before
#  1: 2018-01-01  1            0
#  2: 2018-01-02  2            0
#  3: 2018-01-03  3            0
#  4: 2018-01-04  4            0
#  5: 2018-01-05  3            1
#  6: 2018-01-06  5            0
#  7: 2018-01-07  2            1
#  8: 2018-01-08  2            2
#  9: 2018-01-09  1            1
# 10: 2018-01-10  4            1
```